Display Vaadin Date-Time Picker in a Column Layout
I want to display a datetimepicker in a column layout with Vaadin 23.
DateTimePicker dateTimePicker = new DateTimePicker();
dateTimePicker.addClassName("stacked");
add(dateTimePicker);


It is made up of two inputs. If I put the CSS properties below, it doesn't make it column.
display: flex;
flex-direction: column; 

I looked in the shadow root of this element, and a container appears below.
<div class="vaadin-date-time-picker-container"> 
    <div class="slots"> 
        <slot name="date-picker" id="dateSlot"></slot> 
        <slot name="time-picker" id="timeSlot"></slot> 
    </div> 
</div>

When I apply the css properties in the Chrome inspection tool at the div.slots, my 2 inputs are displayed in columns. So I used this selector in my css file, but it doesn't work.
// In the file at: frontend/themes/common-theme/styles.css
:host(.stacked) .slots {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; 
}

Do you have an idea or solution?

Looking at their document it is implemented using Web Components. Not sure where you put that CSS code, but  :host won't select the correct element from the outside, and slots can't be selected by .slot. This is the nature of web components. You need define the parts and target the correct part instead. They have a dedicated guide on how to do this: How to Selectively Style a Sub-component of a Vaadin Component

Also what does display in a column layout mean? Which part of the date-time picker are you targeting? There are year, months, and multiple time containers. Please [edit] your question and explain your goal.

@SyndRain I edited my post. I hope it will be clearer!

1- Solution 1:
public class CustomDateTimePicker extends DateTimePicker {
public CustomDateTimePicker() {
    addClassName("stacked");
    // Optional: Set other properties
    setDatePlaceholder("Select date");
    setTimePlaceholder("Select time");
  }
}

2- Solution 2:
DateTimePicker dateTimePicker = new DateTimePicker();
dateTimePicker.addClassName("stacked");
add(dateTimePicker);

and for the css can be set in main styles.css file :
vaadin-date-time-picker.stacked::part(input-fields) {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 8px;
}

